# Search form is not working It is freeze

Tags: jquery, html, css

my search for is not working after making changes in my main menu . I created a drop down menu but now problem is with my search field which inline with main menu. It is freeze when move cursor in it nothing happened with it .

```css
div.mainmenu { background: url('images/body-bg.gif') 0px -50px repeat-x; }
div.mainmenu div.center { background: url('images/body-bg.gif') 0px -50px repeat-x;
 border-bottom-color: #007399; border-left: none; border-right: none; }

ul.mainmenu { position: relative; height: 28px; padding: 4px 0px 5px 0px; }
ul.mainmenu li { list-style-type: none; float: left; padding: 5px 10px 5px 12px; margin: 0px; font-size: 15px; }
ul.mainmenu li a { color: #000;  }
ul.mainmenu li a:hover { color: #e0f0ff; }

ul.mainmenu img { width: 20px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px; }

ul.dropdown { position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 24px; margin: 0; display: none; background: #ccc; padding: 0; max-width: 100px; }
ul.mainmenu li:hover .dropdown, .dropdown:hover { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu">
  <div class="center">
  <div class="body">
   <div class="searchbox">
    <form action="<?=$site_folder?>/search.php" method="GET">
     <input type="text" class="text" name="search" value="<?=$_REQUEST['search']?>" />
     <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
   </div>
   
   <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('home')?>">Best Forex Broker</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('toprated')?>">Top Rated Brokers</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('coupons')?>"> Forex Bonus</a>

<ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">drop1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">drop2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">drop3</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('articles')?>">Articles & Tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('affiliates')?>">Affiliate Programs</a></li>
    <li>
     <a href="<?=MakeUrl('feeds')?>"><img src="<?=$site_folder?>/images/rss.png" alt="RSS" /></a>
     
    </li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

I hope someone will help me here again .

Comment: "It is freeze when move cursor in it nothing happened with it ." what actually u want to say with this line..make it more clear

Comment: Hello Tania , I mean now search form is not clickable or writable.. mean when I click in search field it doesn't allow me to write there anything . Even search button is also not clickable.  Hope you understand... if you want url then I can send ,,

Comment: but the field is clickable when i run the code in fiddle...it will be convenient if u share ur url

Comment: Hello.. here is the url ..http://onlineforexbusiness.com/affiliate-programs/  open and check search field..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ul.mainmenu {
 position: relative;
 height: 28px;
 padding: 4px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

In this you have includes `position:relative` i dont know the purpose of it at this moment of time but if you remove this or replace with `position:inherit` you searchbox will work.

Comment: I just changed css to position:inherit   Now look at my website . http://onlineforexbusiness.com/affiliate-programs/  Menu disturbed ...